# Генерация и передача Hash через tls

Tags: golang, tls

Как правильно сгенерировать hash на стороне сервера и передать его на клиент используя стандартную библиотеку crypto/..., а то  на данный момент при генерации, через sha512 данные при передачи меняются. 
У меня вот такое есть:

```
str := []byte("asdadasdadadssasdsdasdsas")
bytes28 := md5.Sum([]byte(str))
```

Далее я отправляю string(bytes28) на клиент, потом с клиента пытаюсь получить доступ к данным на сервер по данному hash коду, но код изменился при транспортировке, в следствии чего данные не выбираются.

Comment: Если у вас код изменяется при транспортировке, то, наверное, проблема именно в способе передачи хэша в одну или другую сторону, поэтому неплохо бы добавить данных о том, как именно передаётся (а не вычисляется) хэш в обе стороны.

Comment: Удваиваю комментарий Романа.